# Scroll through muntidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Moeda] => AUDCAD [Data1] => 2020-11-27 10:20 [Hora] => 10:20:00 [Vela] => Verde [Timeframe] => 1 )
 [1] => Array ( [Moeda] => AUDCAD [Data1] => 2020-11-26 10:20 [Hora] => 10:20:00 [Vela] => Vermelha [Timeframe] => 1 )
 [2] => Array ( [Moeda] => AUDCAD [Data1] => 2020-11-25 10:20 [Hora] => 10:20:00 [Vela] => Verde [Timeframe] => 1 ) )
```

and I'm trying to go through his fields like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {          
        foreach($resultados[$i] as $key => $value) {
               $horario = $value->Hora;
               print_r('Horario: '. $horario); 
                
                if (!in_array($horario, $analise))
                {
                $arr = array($horario => array('Verde'=> 0, 'Vermelha'=> 0, 'Doji'=> 0, '%'=> 0, 'dir'=> ''));
                   $analise = array_merge($analise, $arr);
                    print_r( "concat\n");
                    print_r($analise);
                }
                
                $analise[$horario][$value['Vela']] += 1;
                
                try{

                    $analise[$horario]['%'] = round(100 * ($analise[$horario]['Verde'] / ($analise[$horario]['Verde'] + $analise[$horario]['Vermelha'] + $analise[$horario]['Doji'])));
                    echo "passou do try\n";
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
        }
         
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop your line

`for($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {`

just do the foreach

`foreach($resultados AS $key => $value){`

Call values this this

`$horario = $value['Hora'];`

Answer (score 0):

maybe use 2 foreach, like

```
foreach($resultado as $i1 => $v1){
  foreach($v1 as $i2=>$v2){
    .....
  }
}
```